# Delete impala shell history

Tags: shell, hadoop, impala

I face this problem: We have a shared user where we use impala-shell from the same machine for impala queries. I don't want my queries to be visible and I want to be able to clear my impala-shell history. We access impala with:

```
impala-shell
```

an any user by using the up-key can see all the queries.How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the history file, located in your home folder.

```
rm ~/.impalahistory
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @funkyjelly answer, 
you can also override IMPALA_HISTFILE to another location and delete it too or have individual ones per real user.

In [impala_shell_config_defaults.py](https://github.com/apache/impala/blob/master/shell/impala_shell_config_defaults.py#L26) you have:

```
_histfile_from_env = os.environ.get(
    'IMPALA_HISTFILE', '~/.impalahistory')
...
```